# How can i add custom marker to map using react-map-gl?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, geojson, react-map-gl

i want to add custom marker to my map. Im using react-map-gl library and components Layer and Source.  My code is:

```
import pin from "../images/pin.svg";
```

. . . .

```
const geojson: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry>  = {
            type: 'Feature' ,
            geometry:{
                type: 'Point' as 'Point', 
                coordinates:[21.300465619950796 , 48.70795452044564],
            },
            properties: {
                name: "Marker",

              }
          };
          const layerStyle = {
            id: 'point',
            type: 'symbol' as 'symbol',
            source: 'Marker',
            layout: {
                'icon-image': 'pin',
                'icon-size': 1
            },
            paint: {
              'icon-color': '#78546'
    
            },
          };
```

.
.
.
.

```
<Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={geojson}>
   <Layer {...layerStyle} />
</Source>
```

But my icon doesnt appear. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Basically mapbox needs to have a reference of the image already stored before it can assigned it to a pin/marker in a layer symbol.

Here is what I did, and hope it helps you

1. First create a `onLoad` function that will be called when the map loads

```js
<Map
  ...
  ref={mapRef} // need a ref to reference it later if you don't have it already
  onLoad={onLoad}
/>
```

2. In the `onLoad` function create a new image and load its content

```js
const onLoad = (e) => {
  if (mapRef.current) {
    const pinImage = new Image();
    pinImage.onload = () => {
      if (!mapRef.current.hasImage('pin')) {
        mapRef.current.addImage('pin', pinImage, { sdf: true });
      }
    }
    pinImage.src = pin; // pin is your svg import
  }
}
```

It should now work with your current layer attributes, please note that the name given in the `addImage` call (the first argument 'pin') must match the `image-icon` in the layer settings.

**Note:** Also make sure the layer style `source` attribute matches that of its source id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
export const DirectionsMap: FC<DirecMapProps> = ({ center, markers }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapboxConfig(center);

    markers?.forEach(({ startPos }) => {
      const el = document.createElement("div");
      el.className = "custom-marker";

      new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat([startPos.longitude, startPos.latitude])
        .addTo(map);

      createRoot(el).render(<FaCar className="text-green-400" size={20} />);
    });

    return () => map.remove();

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" className="w-[100vw] h-[100vh]" />;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
import ReactMapGL, {Marker} from 'react-map-gl';

<ReactMapGL width="100vw" height="100vh">
  <Marker longitude={longitude} latitude={latitude} >
    <img src={pin} />
  </Marker>
</ReactMapGL>
```

Comment: this dont work for me because then marker image is not on the correct position. Thats why i want to use the Layer component and symbol.

Comment: You should add offset to marker ```offsetLeft={-markerSize / 2} offsetTop={-markerSize}```

Comment: @SchemeSonic No this is not what the OP asked for nor the solution to its problem, the maker(s) need to be in contained in a layer not on its own.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez I think you are confused between  mapboxgl and react-map-gl. He does not need an extra layer to display custom markers. There is already existing Marker component in react-map-gl.  Check out https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/blob/7.0-release/examples/controls/src/app.tsx

Comment: @SchemeSonic the OP is clearly stating the use of `Source` & `Layers` with `react-map-gl`, not a `Marker` component on its own.